# If a pure function returns an impure function is it pure

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

If a pure function returns an impure function is it pure

```
const fn = endpoint => () => { 
  console.log(endpoint);
}
```

Technically `fn` is pure is it not?

Comment: This is actually the foundation of the IO Monad. Everything stays pure as long as you don't call the thunk (fun with no arguments). Now to be able to do something useful with this, you need 1) a way to combine such a function with another (partially applied) IO computation 2) a mechanism to allow such functions to work with normal (pure) values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the outer function is pure. The calling of the function doesn't cause any side effects beyond the background mechanisms required for the creation of a lambda (and if you counted those effects, no functions would be pure, as at the very least the call stack is altered by the function call).

You could replace this function call with the function that it returns inline, and the code would behave identically.

Comment: I had the names mixed up originally. Fixed now.

Comment: could you please comment my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with @Carcigenicate. A function `f` is pure if an expression `f(x)` is referentially transparent for every referentially transparent expression `x`. 
It means that you can replace `f(x)` with some VALUE and observable behavior of the program won't change. It's not the case for `console.log`.

It's different than in, say, Haskell, where `IO` is a true value, not a side-effecting statement.

Comment: "It means that you can replace f(x) with some VALUE and observable behavior of the program won't change." That's the case here. You could replace the function call with the function that's returned and the behavior would be the same. The inner function is certainly impure due to the `console.log` call, but the outer function never calls the inner one

Comment: So you are proposing to allow terms to be side-effecting? Then it becomes illegal to reduce `() => {console.log}` to `console.log`. Otherwise all desired properties of lambda-calculus (which is a only way to talk about RT afaik) are lost.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what you're referring to in the first two sentences. I'm saying that the call to `fn` could be replaced by the returned function `() => { console.log(endpoint); }` inline, and the behavior of the program would be identical, and that `fn` itself does not cause any side effects. Which point are you arguing against?

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for explanation.